# Mono for Android Saving data

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I created a homescreen widget, that gets a table of strings from a website. Instead of getting data from web on every update, I want to save the table to the phone and than read from the file on update. I'm using Mono for Android (C#).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method for saving data to the file system using XML Serialization

```
    public static bool SaveData<T>(Context context, string fileName, T data)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = context.OpenFileOutput(fileName, FileCreationMode.Private))
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, data);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And here is a method for loading serialized data from the file system

```
    public static T LoadData<T>(Context context, string fileName)
    {
        Java.IO.File file = context.GetFileStreamPath(fileName);

        if (file.Exists())
        {
            using (Stream openStream = context.OpenFileInput(fileName))
            {
               using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openStream))
               {
                   try
                   {
                       XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                       var loadedObject = serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                       return (T)loadedObject;
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       // TODO Handle error

                       return default(T);
                   }
               }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Java.IO.FileNotFoundException("Could not find file " + fileName);
        }
    }
```

Using these methods you can easily save and load any serializable object such as a `string[]` you retrieved from the website.

```
  string[] data = { "one", "two", "three" };

  JavaIO.SaveData(this, "SavedData.txt", data);

  string[] loadedData = JavaIO.LoadData<string[]>(this, "SavedData.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a simple list, then you can use System.IO.File to load/save text - and you can use something like JSON.Net to convert your list to/from text.

If your data is more incremental, then you can use SQLite instead - try the the SQLite-net ORM wrapper on GitHub

Comment: Tried IO.FILE and TextWriter, both don't work. Is there a c# android specific command?